# Saving File to Parse sometimes works, sometimes throws "IllegalStateException: Unable to encode an unsaved ParseFile"

Tags: android, image, exception, parse-platform

So I've been working with this bit of code today and I can't seem to figure out what is causing this ParseException to throw. Sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't. What seems to cause the throw is when there is more data in each field to be uploaded to Parse. When there is minimal data, the item saves with it's photo and there is no problem. I read that it could be that I'm not setting up the ParseFile before adding it to the object, but I am and I tried switching that code around to no avail. Any ideas what might be causing it?

```
public class AddItemActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText mItemName;
    private String mItemNameString;
    private EditText mItemDescription;
    private String mItemDescriptionString;
    private EditText mItemPrice;
    private String mItemPriceString;
    private Button mAddItemButton;
    private Date mAddDate;
    private String mAddDateString;
    private boolean mItemSoldBoolean;
    private ImageView mDeleteButton;
    private ImageView mBackButton;
    private ImageView mAddImageIcon;
    private TextView mAddImageLabel;
    private Bitmap mItemImageBitmap;
    private byte[] mItemImageByteArray;
    private ProgressBar mUploadProgress;
    private ParseObject mNewItem;
    private ParseFile mItemImageFile;
    private boolean mCameraUsed = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_item);
        mUploadProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.uploadProgress);
        mUploadProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        mDeleteButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
        mDeleteButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        mAddImageIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.addImageIcon);
        mAddImageLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addItemLabel);
        mBackButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backButton);
        mBackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                goBack();
            }
        });

        mAddImageIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.addImageIcon);
        mAddImageIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                takePhoto();
            }
        });

        mAddItemButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitItemButton);
        mAddItemButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mAddItemButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mCameraUsed) {
                    saveItemToInventory();
                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddItemActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle("THERE'S NO PHOTO!")
                            .setMessage("You haven't added an photo of your item! Would you like to add one now, or continue and add one later?")
                            .setPositiveButton("TAKE PHOTO NOW", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    takePhoto();
                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton("CONTINUE WITHOUT PHOTO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            saveItemToInventory();
                                            mCameraUsed = false;
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                    builder.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void takePhoto() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 4);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
            switch(requestCode) {
                case 4:
                    Bundle photo = data.getExtras();
                    mItemImageBitmap = (Bitmap) photo.get("data");
                    if (mItemImageBitmap != null) {
                        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        mItemImageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                        mItemImageByteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                    }
                    mAddImageIcon.setImageBitmap(mItemImageBitmap);
                    mAddImageLabel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    mCameraUsed = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void goBack() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(AddItemActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void finish() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(AddItemActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void saveItemToInventory() {
        mAddItemButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mUploadProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mItemName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.itemNameField);
        mItemNameString = mItemName.getText().toString().trim();
        mItemDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.itemDescriptionField);
        mItemDescriptionString = mItemDescription.getText().toString().trim();
        mItemPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.itemPriceField);
        mItemPriceString = mItemPrice.getText().toString().trim();
        mAddDate = new Date();
        mAddDateString = mAddDate.toString();
        mItemSoldBoolean = false;

        if (!mCameraUsed){
            mItemImageBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)mAddImageIcon.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            mItemImageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            mItemImageByteArray = stream.toByteArray();
            mItemImageFile = new ParseFile(mItemNameString + ".png", mItemImageByteArray);
            mItemImageFile.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null){
                        createObject();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(AddItemActivity.this, "There was an error. " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            mItemImageFile = new ParseFile(mItemNameString + ".jpg", mItemImageByteArray);
            mItemImageFile.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        createObject();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(AddItemActivity.this, "There was an error. " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void createObject() {
        mNewItem = new ParseObject("Item");
        mNewItem.put("name", mItemNameString);
        mNewItem.put("description", mItemDescriptionString);
        mNewItem.put("addDate", mAddDateString);
        mNewItem.put("price", mItemPriceString);
        mNewItem.put("itemSold", mItemSoldBoolean);
        mNewItem.put("itemImage", mItemImageFile);
        mNewItem.setACL(new ParseACL(ParseUser.getCurrentUser()));
        mNewItem.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    mUploadProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Well.... this is ridiculous. So I mentioned it was working SOMETIMES but not OTHERS.... well... it's because I had illegal characters in my file name. I was using the mItemNameString, which could have been "2011 Kawasaki Ninja"... but that is not a legal file name. Instead, I had to use the `.replace()` method to `.replace(" ", "")`, essentially removing all spaces from the file name. Now... NO problems. This was a tricky one to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

do parse file in asynctask and do encoding on asynctask's onPostExecute